# How to turn "ticking" answers from a survey into categorical variables

Tags: r, variables, survey, categorical

I have a survey in which we have some questions where you tick the answers, as in the following image

[image: Survey]

The dataset looks like this [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkyVp.jpg)

I need to turn the answers in my data set into categorical variables, such as this one:

| ID | Choice | Choice_Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sun/Solar Photovoltaic, Wind Power | 1, 2 |
| 2 | Wind Power, Hydel | 2, 3 |

Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance

at first I tried this command

```
data <- structure(list(CIQ_RES_choice = c("Sun/Solar Photovoltaic", "Wind Power",
"Hydel", "Biomass", "Geothermal", "Food crops", "I do not know Renewable Energy Sources")),
class ="data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

as.data.frame(apply(data,1,function(x) {x<-as.numeric(factor(x,levels = unique(x)))}))
```

But I get a vector with 7 values such as this one

| ID | Choice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sun/Solar Photovoltaic |
| 2 | Wind Power |
| 3 | Hydel |

Comment: Welcome to SO, Luca Mariani! It's not clear how you expect to determine `Choice_Cat`, is that from the sample `data` you provided? I don't see clear numbers (other than row numbers, which I'm not assuming are correct). Where is `ID` from?

Comment: Thanks for answering! No, Choice_cat is the outcome I would like to obtain. ID is indeed from the database and represents each of the respondents from the survey. I want to turn the choices they made on the survey (each of the renewable sources they know) into categorical variables, so that if someone chose Sun/Solar Photovoltaic and Hydel, I will get a cell that contains the values 1 and 3.

Comment: Great. Where is the survey data? We only have `ID` in the desired output.

Comment: I put an image with an example of the data in the main body of the post. Thanks for helping me out so far.

Comment: I think I am not understanding. What is the input you get from the survey? Is it a csv or otherwise structured file? Or is it an image of checkboxes that you have to scrape?

Comment: From the survey I get an xlsx file with the answers to it. I have to turn that answer (about renewable sources) into something that I can analyze/interpret and use in a regression model.

Comment: If you need help converting survey-data to something else, please provide survey-data (and please not a picture of it). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for demonstrations of using `dput` and friends, and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for why pics of data/code are discouraged. Thanks!